# Trying to understand Sequent Calculus inference rules for quantifiers $\forall$ and $\exists$.

Tags: first-order-logic, quantifiers, sequent-calculus

I'm trying to understand any of the **LK sequent calculus (logic) inference rules for quantifiers** (if I can understand one well enough, perhaps I can use that to inform my understanding of the other three). Per [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequent_calculus#Inference_rules), the rules are:

|  | $L$ | $R$ |
| --- | --- | --- |
| $\forall$ | $$\Gamma, A[t/x] \vdash \Delta \over \Gamma, \forall xA \vdash \Delta$$ | $$\Gamma \vdash A[y/x], \Delta\over \Gamma \vdash \forall xA, \Delta$$ |
| $\exists$ | $$\Gamma, A[y/x] \vdash \Delta \over \Gamma, \exists xA \vdash \Delta$$ | $$\Gamma \vdash A[t/x], \Delta \over \Gamma \vdash \exists xA, \Delta$$ |

The Wikipedia article says this about these rules:

> For an intuition about the quantifier rules, consider the rule $({\forall }R)$. Of course concluding that $\forall{x} A$ holds just from the fact that $A[y/x]$ is true is not in general possible. If, however, the variable y is not mentioned elsewhere (i.e. it can still be chosen freely, without influencing the other formulae), then one may assume, that $A[y/x]$ holds for any value of $y$. The other rules should then be pretty straightforward.

(First question: The inference rules use both $A[t/x]$ and $A[y/x]$. Is there a difference between $A[t/x]$ and $A[y/x]$? I know $t$ conventionally denotes a term. Does $y$ also?)

The same Wikipedia article states the meaning of the notation $A[t/x]$:

> $A[t/x]$ denotes the formula that is obtained by substituting the term $t$ for every free occurrence of the variable $x$ in formula $A$ with the restriction that the term $t$ must be free for the variable $x$ in $A$ (i.e., no occurrence of any variable in $t$ becomes bound in $A[t/x]$).

It should also be noted that in sequent calculus

- a term $t$ has no quantifiers (or any binders) hence all of its variables are free
- a formula $A$ may have quantifiers. It may also have free variables. Hence, it may have bound variables and free variables.

---

Why are the rules of the form:

$$\Gamma, A[t/x] \vdash \Delta \over \Gamma, \forall xA \vdash \Delta$$

instead of of the form:

$$\Gamma, A \vdash \Delta \over \Gamma, \forall xA \vdash \Delta$$

Why are the substitutions necessary? For a particular rule, does the substitution ensure that $x$ is a free variable?

Comment: "Is there a difference between A[t/x] and A[y/x]?" Yes, $t$ is a *term* while $y$ is a variable. A *term* may be either a variable, or a constant or a "complex" term (like e.g. $(x+0)\times y$ in the language of arithmetic).

Comment: The $(\forall \text L)$ says: if $A$ does not hold for some "object" denoted by *term* $t$, i.e. $A[t/x]$ is false, then $\forall x A$ does not hold, i.e. it is false that every objects is $A$.

Comment: The $(\exists \text R)$ rule is "symmetric:  if $A$ holds for some "object" denoted by term t, i.e. $A[t/x]$ is true, then $\exists xA$ holds, i.e. it is true that some object is $A$. In both case we use a term $t$ to pick a "specific" object.

Comment: In the other pair of rules, we use a variable $y$ to refer to an "unspecified" object. Thus, the $(\exists \text L)$ rule says: if $A$ does not hold for an "object" whatever (here we can use a variable $y$ whatever, provided that we have not used it elsewhere in te derivation), i.e. $A[y/x]$ is false, then $\exists xA$ does not hold, i.e. 
 it is false that there is some object that is $A$. The same for $(\forall \text R)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had a careful observation for the difference between arbitrary term $t$ and arbitrary variable $y$ used in the 4 quantifier rules in $LK$. Indeed there's some purpose for this difference intentionally in most sequent calculi.

Recall $\forall$L implicitly corresponds to $\forall$-elim of natural deduction, so if $A$ holds for every object then we can substitute any term $t$, however complex, into $A$ for $x$ (of course assuming $t$ is free for $x$ in $A$), and then if we can still derive $\Delta$ that's when $\forall$L makes sense. Conversely, $\forall$R corresponds to $\forall$-intro rule in ND, so we need an arbitrary *single* variable $y$ (assuming $y$ is not mentioned elsewhere) to substitute for $x$ in $A$ to be derived as a result of $\Gamma$ as the most generic case to introduce $\forall x A$.

And interestingly, for the $\exists$ quantifier the situations reverse since in the introduction case ($\exists$R rule) usually a generic variable $y$ won't qualify to derive $A(y)$ from $\Gamma$, you need to work hard to find a specific term $t$ satisfying $\Gamma \vdash A[t/x]$. Similar reasoning for $\exists$L rule.

Finally if you understand $\forall$L rule as $\forall$-elim of natural deduction, then you can easily see from same above reasoning you have to prove $\Delta$ from $\Gamma$ and $A[t/x]$ for an arbitrary term, only then $\forall$L makes sense and holds.

Comment: Thanks! How can I think of $A$? It's a formula with (possibly) a free variable $x$. That variable $x$ - can it be seen as an input or argument into $A$? Does $x$ represents an object? When I substitute variable $y$ for $x$, is that like plugging in a specific or generic entity into $A$? When I substitute term $t$ for $x$, what does that represent?

Comment: @joseville Variable $x$ is an argument and represents any object from the domain of your specific FOL at hand as quantifier only ranges over domain. For example $A$ is defined as $(x+1)(x-1)=x^2-1$ and the domain is given as $\mathbb R$. So $x$ represents any real number, and clearly we have $\forall xA(x)$ in this case. When using R rule, you need to substitute a generic single variable $y$ to derive $A[y/x]$ and in this case it's obvious per elementary algebra and you don't even need $\Gamma$. When using L rule, you substitute arbitrary term such as $t=f(y)$ to prove $\Delta$

Comment: Thanks. Why was it necessary to substitute $y$ for $x$ to get $A[y/x]$? Don't $A$ and $A[y/x]$ have the same meaning?

Comment: @joseville in my above example when using $\forall$R rule, $A=A(x)$ which is defined as $(x+1)(x−1)=x^2−1$. From elementary algebra we know we can derive this without any additional premise $\Gamma$ under the usual structure of closed real field, but how do you rigorously prove $\forall xA(x)$? To invoke the R rule, we have to verify for a *generic* variable $y$ representing any object from the domain and substitute for $x$, $A[y/x]$ holds (which can be easily done following the axioms of real field). You can also think of $y$ as an arbitrary constant $c$, mere $A$ doesn't have this process...

Comment: Silly question. If the domain of discourse is living organisms and $A(x)$ is the formula saying $x$ is an animal. $y$ as a variable could be a stand in for a specific dog? And so we could say $A[y/x]$ holds. What would an example of a term $t$? If $Q(x)$ is the predicate $x$ has four legs, would $t = Q(x)$ be a term representing an animal with four legs?

Comment: @joseville $t=Q(x)$ cannot be a term if $Q$ is a predicate symbol, to qualify as [term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic#Terms) *it has to be a variable, or an expression f(t1,...,tn) of n arguments (where each argument ti is a term and f is a function symbol of valence n), or expressions which can be obtained by finitely many applications of rules 1 and 2... no expression involving a predicate symbol is a term.* In your example, although A(dog) holds, but dog is not a *generic* representative from the domain (there're lots of non-animals), so you cannot prove ∀xA(x)...

Comment: @joseville ...a term in your example could be y=fatherOf(x), and it's perfectly fine in FOL that we don't have any function symbols available, so we can only talk of realtions/properties, like a partial order set with only relation symbol <...

Answer (score 1):

Because we **don't** just want to slap a "$\forall x$" on the front of the formula $A$. *(For simplicity, below I work with $\Gamma=\emptyset$ and $\Delta$ a single formula, namely $\Delta=\exists xU(x)$.)*

For example, suppose $A$ is the formula $U(c)$ where $U$ is a unary predicate symbol and $c$ is a constant symbol. From the sequent $$U(c)\vdash\exists xU(x)$$ (whose derivation I leave as an exercise) we would like to infer the sequent $$\forall xU(x)\vdash \exists xU(x).$$ However, your version of the ${\forall}L$ rule would only give us $$\forall xU(c)\vdash\exists xU(x),$$ and this isn't at all the same thing.

Comment: Thanks. I copied the rules from the Wikipedia article. In the rules, should $\forall xA$ be $\forall A(x)$ and should $\exists xA$ be $\exists xA(x)$?